# Add BioStructures package into Julia

Tags: package, julia

I'm new to Julia. I need to using a package called BioStructures in Julia for my project. Here is the link for the package: [BioStructures](https://github.com/BioJulia/BioStructures.jl)

It seems like I successfully added BioStructures.jl in Julia. But when I typed `using BioStructures`, it will show up 4 errors. Please help me if u know how to fix it.
[image]

```
julia> using BioStructures
[ Info: Precompiling BioStructures [de9282ab-8554-53be-b2d6-f6c222edabfc]
ERROR: LoadError: type DataType has no field size

ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile JLD2 [033835bb-8acc-5ee8-8aae-3f567f8a3819] to "/Users/jingyi/.julia/compiled/v1.9/JLD2/jl_CBHsUi".

ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile MetaGraphs [626554b9-1ddb-594c-aa3c-2596fe9399a5] to "/Users/jingyi/.julia/compiled/v1.9/MetaGraphs/jl_LoKoZa".

ERROR: Failed to precompile BioStructures [de9282ab-8554-53be-b2d6-f6c222edabfc] to "/Users/jingyi/.julia/compiled/v1.9/BioStructures/jl_JHajOy".
```

Comment: I'm using MacBook Air M2

Comment: Have you added the other packages in its dependencies? Looks like it needs `JLD2` and `MetaGraphs`.

Comment: How did you install julia into your MacBook? Did you conda install it?

Comment: and which version of Julia you are using?

Comment: I installed Julia by downloading from [here](https://julialang.org/downloads/) , and now I'm using 1.9.2

Comment: I recommend you to use `juliaup`, since it is also super easy to install in the mac (see my answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problems when I did `conda install -c conda-forge julia` which installed Julia v1.9.3. Installations of Julia packages, which should work, e.g. `add Genie` didn't work with that Julia (there, the packages `MbedTLS` and `HTTP` created problems).

## Use Juliaup

The problem disappeared, when I installed `juliaup` instead.
It is a manager for installing and switching between different Julia versions. So very useful.

For the conda environment, to install `juliaup` was as easy as:

```
conda install -c conda-forge juliaup
```

(I generated a new conda environment for that `conda create --name juliaup` and then `conda activate juliaup` - and deleted the "julia" environment `conda env remove --name julia`).

If you don't use a conda environment, on a Mac, you do simply:

```
brew install juliaup
```

Install the newest version of julia into `juliaup` via the command:

```
juliaup add release

# and then call the newest julia version by:
julia +release
```

In this Julia, `add Genie` worked just fine. I also just tried `add BioStructures` there - it works fine.

## Use OS repository Julia

Also the Julia from the main Ubuntu repository was working smoothly:

```
sudo snap install julia --classic
```

So, for your MacOS it would be:

```
brew install julia
```

Comment: You should not use the OS julia repository. They are usually broken.

Comment: @OscarSmith is it? What one should then use? `juliaup` is a good way, it seemed for me.

Comment: juliaup or the official binaries